# The relation between RP, BPP and NP

Tags: complexity-classes

I have the following thoughts so I'd like to hear are there any straightforward implications which might support or undermine them.

You have a class BPP where problems have a TM with bounded two side error and constant ratio of correct leaves in your computational tree.

You have a class NP, which you can think of there is a TM with computational tree which is correct for no instances , but for yes instance $x$ you can have the correct leaves ration as small as $\frac{1}{2^{p(|x|)}}$.

If you kind of combine this you get for no instances all leaves correct for yes instances only the constant ratio, and this is class RP.

So the conjecture is $RP = NP \cap BPP$. What are the important implications? Is there a 1-line proof?

From me, I can add that the widely believed conjecture $BPP = P$ definitely supports the claim.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this conjecture is known. It certainly doesn't have any one line proof.

Comment: Any major implications, except just "neat class relation"?

Comment: (Your conjecture would also follow from ​ BPP = ZPP , ​ which is weaker than ​ BPP = P .) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: This is not known. However, it is known (and fairly easy) that $\mathrm{NP\subseteq BPP}$ implies $\mathrm{NP=RP}$. I have a déjà-vu feeling that this was already discussed somewhere on this site.